# Twilio webrtc client: Error "ICE negotiation with Twilio failed" after first call

Tags: twilio, webrtc

I'm running a node server (v10.12.0) in ubuntu (16.04.5) running on port 443. I have created a Twiml app in Twilio to route incoming calls to my webrtc client. 
My JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("/token/generate", function(data) {
    Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);
  });
});

/* Callback for when Twilio Client initiates a new connection */
Twilio.Device.connect(function (connection) {
  //In call...
});

/* Callback for when Twilio Client receives a new incoming call */
Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
  connection.accept(function() {
    //In call...
  });
  answerButton.click(function() {
    connection.accept();
  });
});

/* End a call */
function hangUp() {
  Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}
```

When I load the page for first time, I can receive the incoming call without any errors. But when I call again without reloading the page there is an error:

> ERROR: ICE negotiation with Twilio failed. Call will terminate.

When I answer the second call, chrome console shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sdp' of null
>       at g.getSDP (twilio.min.js:103)
>       at twilio.min.js:95

I already looked into this [doc](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133067-What-are-ICE-errors-) by twilio and I verified that there is no issue with firewall.

So I added code to reload the page after disconnecting a call.

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(connection) {
  // Reloading page to avoid ICE error.
  location.reload();
});
```

I wonder if anybody knows any solution other than reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

I was using twilio client api version 1.3. I changed it to 1.4 (media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.min.js). Now it seems to be working.